# Electric potential on conductor

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

In the above question , there will be induction of charge on inner sphere , hence on its surface there must be non zero value of electric potential . But in the solution , the electric potential on the surface of inner sphere has been taken as zero.
Inner sphere is connected to earth does it mean that electric potential on its surface is zero despite of charge on the sphere ?

Does it mean that any conductor even if it has charge is connected to earth will have zero electric potential?
I can't digest this , pls provide some useful insights

Answer (score 0):

Because the inner sphere is stated to be grounded, its electric potential is zero. However, there must be a nonzero charge on the inner sphere's surface.

If there were no charge on the inner sphere, and there were charge on the outer shell only, then the electric potential of the inner sphere would not be zero. Recall that, to determine the electric potential at a point $P$, we integrate the electric field on a path from infinity to $P$ (and then multiply by -1). With the outer shell having a charge of $Q$ = 6 μC, it will produce an electric field directed radially outward. To get the electric potential at the inner shell, we integrate:

$$ V = - \int_\infty^{r_1} E \cdot \mathrm{d}r = \int_{r_1}^{r_2} E \cdot \mathrm{d}r + \int_{r_2}^\infty E \cdot \mathrm{d}r $$

where $r_1$ = 1 m and $r_2$ = 3 m. In the region from $r_1$ to $r_2$ (outside the inner sphere, but inside the outer shell) the charge on the outer shell does not contribute to the electric field. In the region from $r_2$ to $\infty$, $E$ will be given by Coulomb's law and $E \cdot \mathrm{d}r$ is positive. This implies that $V$ is positive.

In order for $V$ to be zero, there needs to be negative charge on the inner sphere that produces an electric field directed radially inward whose contribution to $V$ should cancel out the contribution made by the outer shell's field. However, that does not mean that $E$ itself should be cancelled. If you put -6 μC of charge on the inner sphere, it will cancel the outer sphere's field in the outermost region, $r > r_2$, but there will be a leftover electric field between the inner sphere and the shell, resulting in a negative value of $V$.

Rather, because the outer sphere has 3 times as much capacitance as the inner sphere, it means that a unit of charge placed on the inner sphere will affect its potential 3 times as much as if it were placed on the outer sphere. This implies that the charge on the inner sphere is -2 μC.

Answer (score 0):

You should not confuse the field variables electrical charge density $\rho$ and electrical potential $\phi$. The electrical potential can be choosen arbitrarily. It is more important to understand the Gauss law

$ \oint_{\partial  \Omega} \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \int_{\Omega} \rho \mathrm{d}V \equiv Q $

and the relation between the volume integral and the (closed) surface integral. Note that

$\nabla \phi = -\mathbf{E}$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).